# How to prevent electron app from closing by task manager

Tags: electron, preventdefault, taskmanager

I want to create an application that can't be closed by task manager.
I do prevent application closing from taskbar, minimize the window and put it in tray but couldn't handle task manager closing.
I'm wondering if anyone could help me.

Here's the snippet:

```
mainWindow.on('close', (event) => {
    if (!canClose) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mainWindow.minimize();
        mainWindow.setSkipTaskbar(true);
    } else {
        if (appIcon) appIcon.destroy();
        app.quit();
    }
});

canClose => let, appIcon => Tray
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.on('before-quit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

`before-quit` event will be triggered just before `quit` event.

Prevent this event manually then `quit` event won't be triggered.

Comment: Actually this method doesn't work when I close the app from the task manager. (End task) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LDQaROGnNwmtWGd6XWwVVs6MsFnxyk43